# Кому сообщить об орфографических ошибках в интерфейсе ru.stackoverflow?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, stackoverflow

## Ответ:

## [задать новый вопрос на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) с метками [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82), [локализация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Подробнее: [Как принять участие в переводе сайта?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1137/181472)

Пожалуйста, **не сообщайте об ошибках в ответах к этому вопросу**. В таком виде трудно отслеживать их исправление.

---

**Оригинальный вопрос:**

Вернее даже не об ошибках - об опечатках.

Флажки действий для комментариев имеют опечатки в атрибуте title:

```
<a title="Отмететьте комментарий тевогой, чтобы обозначить серьезную проблему или привлечь внимание модератора" class="comment-flag"> тревога </a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сообщения о любых ошибках (включая ошибки перевода) лучше [публиковать прямо здесь, на новой Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1137/181472). Мы постараемся перенести всё обсуждение проекта со старой Меты на новую (выполнено).

Спасибо за замечание, поправили. Для перевода сайта мы используем сервис [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/). Исправление внесли именно там. Как только соберется несколько правок, мы обновим перевод на самом сайте.

Comment: 1. Ээ. Наверное сильное кэширование применяется - на meta.ru.so и на ru.so текст все еще с ошибками.

2. Что-не могу понять - тут есть возможность отправки личных сообщений между участниками?

Comment: @boris_U Обновил ответ.

Comment: @boris_U Пожалуйста, задайте ваш вопрос отдельным вопросом, а не в комментарие.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а ссылку на проект в Transifex можно? Или он приватный?

Comment: [Проект открытый](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/). [Дополнительная](http://meta.hashcode.ru/research/3041/) информация о процессе перевода и [Transifex](http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/3042/).

Comment: При наведении на пункт "править" выводится всплывающая подсказка "Правки-преложения для вопросов не являющихся общими на Мете запрещены.". Пропущена "д" и запятых не хватает. Поправьте хотя бы так: "Правки-предложения для вопросов, не являющихся общими на Мете, запрещены."

Comment: Пробовал также найти некоторые фразы на Transifex, чтобы предложить скорректированные варианты, но их там нет. Например то, о котором я написал выше, или "отметьте тревогой сообщение с целью обозначить серьезную проблему или привлечь внимание модератора". Эту фразу я бы записал как "отметьте тревогой сообщение, если хотите обозначить серьезную проблему или привлечь внимание модератора".

Comment: И ещё довольно странно читать что-нибудь вроде `заморожен по причине всеобъемлющий пользователем`. Возможно, что лучше было бы `заморожен (причина: всеобъемлющий) пользователем`

Comment: @Dmi7ry Поправил "Правки-преложения". Все строки должны быть в Transifex. Если вы не можете найти какую-то строку, скорее всего ее поменяли, но не отметили принятой (вторая галка). В этом случае следует искать по оригинальному (английском) тексту. Если вы считаете, что надо перевести ту или иную строку по-другому, пожалуйста, задавайте соответствующий вопрос на Мете со ссылкой на правку в Transifex.

Comment: Разобрался, что за проблема была с поиском - я делал поиск по странице средствами браузера, но, как ни странно, это не срабатывало, нужно было делать поиск средствами сервиса. Поправьте пожалуйста ещё: `Как начать пользоваться Stack Overflow на русском имея учётную запись на ХэшКоде?` - после "русском" должна быть запятая

Answer (score 2):

Вот ещё опечатка. В "Знаках"

Знак `Констебль`

```
Выполнял обязанности временного модератора не менее 1 года или во время получении степини "зрелого" сайта
```

Заменить "степини" на "степени"

Comment: Проверил, исправлено.

Answer (score 2):

И еще опечатка в "Знаках".

Знак `Популист`

```
Лучший ответ по рейтенгу, превысивший принятый ответ, с более 10 баллами, более чем в 2 раза
```

рейтенгу => рейтингу

Comment: Проверил, исправлено.

Answer (score 2):

Не орфография, а смысловая ошибка на /users/ во всплывающей подсказке (`title=`) ко вкладке «?tab=responses».

Имеется «Ваши недавние реакции», читать «Вызванные [недавние] реакции» или даже, описывая фактическое наполнение, «Встречные комментарии».